# how to filter down a scope in active record using if then?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model that can be in a draft or published form.  I use a boolean attribute draft set to true if the model is a draft.  Set to false if the item is no longer a draft.

When I pull up a list of all these models I want drafts to only be visible to the creator.  While returning all the other models.

scoped = Model.All( if(:draft => true) ) then only select for return if (:creator_id => params[:currentUser)

I want this to return all the models except the drafts that don't belong to the current user.  So scoped would only have drafts that were created by the current user and would still have all the models where draft is set to false.

Can I do this with active record or do I have to do some sore of SQL CASE statment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like this (postgres)?

```
scope :for_user, lambda { |u| where("draft != 't' or (draft = 't' and creator_id = ?)", u.id) }
```

Comment: newbie question here.  How do I access/use the scope?

Comment: Thanks for your help HagrimmTheBleak.   I ended up using this and it seemed to work:   scoped = scoped.where("draft !='t' OR (draft = 't' and creator_id = ?)", params[:currentUserID] )

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get back earlier. Scopes are accessed pretty much as class methods on the model, like `Model.for_user(me)`. Good you've figured it out though. Can you accept the answer if it helped?